# Extruding Roofs out of Surface in Geo Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, geometry

.
Hi
Iam trying to build a building generator. For this i need to extrude the roof from a flat surface.

The Input to the Nodes:
[image: Wireframe Mode of the Buildings]

The optimal Result: (With a mesh subdivision and a triangulate modifier)
[image: Final Result]

I thought it would be a good idea to subdivide the mesh so I have topolgy to create the roof. But I have difficulties selecting the right verticies to move with the Vertex/Edge/Face Neighbor Nodes. I also converting it to a curve and the new Mesh Topology Nodes in 3.4 Alpha but they do not help much either.

Subdivision Applied and the right edges selected manually:
[image]

Has anyone an idea how this could be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only for completion and as an alternative solution:

[image]

1. Subdivide the mesh with the node `Subdivide`.
2. Create a selection of points that have more than $3$ faces.
3. Add to this selection the points that have less than $3$ faces and at the same time the same or more than $3$ vertex neigbors.
4. Move the position of the points with this selection.
5. Triangulate the mesh along the longest diagonal so that the roof has correct edges.
6. (Optional): Additionally use the *Decimate* modifier to remove the excess edges.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>

Comment: Thanks for uploading a complete version. I couldn't upload images for a few days and then forgot about completing my answer

Comment: @soerensc_ You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Lel, found the solution after some experimentation.
For everyone interested the selection setup looks like this:

[image]

And the output roofes like this:

[image]

Comment: the setup will be more readable if you use *Boolean: Not* $(¬x)$ rather than *Math: Substract* $(1-x)$, as well as *Boolean: Or* $(a ∨ b)$ rather than *Math: Add* $(a + b)$. Greater Than or Equal $3$ would also be more readable than *Greater Than* $2.9$ You could also post the entire tree without cropping, because it's not clear how you use this selection, especially as you mix vertex and face attributes.